# how to install new oracle apex theme?

Tags: apache, oracle-apex

I'm trying to install new apex theme but the problem is that I don't know where to put theme images folder in apache webserver?

I tried to put it on the apache/images but this doesn't work

So does anybody know where to put the images folder
Note: I have successfuly imported the .sql file and already switched the theme to the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how the template references the image files.

By default in Apex, there is a substitution value called **#IMAGE_PREFIX#** that points to a folder called **/i/**. This folder, in turn, is just an alias set up in the Apache config (see the dads.conf file to determine the actual location).

Your template should reference images using #IMAGE_PREFIX#some_folder_name/some_file_name, in which case you need to put the images in a folder called "some_folder_name" beneath the directory that the /i/ alias points to.